# What is atom? What constitutes atom?

Tags: scripture, vedas

I'd like to know the "atom". According to Śrī brahma-saṁhitā 5.35,

> "yad-antaḥ aṇḍāntara-stha-paramāṇu-cayāntara-stham"

Kṛṣṇa is present in His fullness in every one of the atoms that are scattered throughout the universe.
I can't figure out atom. It seems like capsule which made from mahat-tattva.
Srila Prabhupada wrote that the atom is the minute subtle form of eternal time.
That confuses me even more.

So, what constitutes atom?

Comment: Rishi Kanada is the famous proponent of parmanu (atom) theory in Brahma Sutras written 5000 years ago. You can check that out.

Comment: @ram I would encourage you to post an answer since you already know the source.

Comment: Atom is the basic unit of Maya Shakti/energy.Everything is made out of atom.Just like a modern movie or video game is projected on screen using bits 0 and 1 and their arrangement through programming, similarly earthly bodies and world is 3d projected using atom by consciousness.What is atomic bomb?Its an uncontrolled explosion of atoms by modern scientists that can mutate organic bodies which are also made out of atoms.Self causes a cluster of atom called body to become conscious, while body withers away in five elements with death or soul leaving body(cluster of Carbon, Oxygen, Hydrogen etc.)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vai%C5%9Be%E1%B9%A3ika_S%C5%ABtra . Anyone interested can pick out the relevant portion and post.

Comment: Thank you guys. I appreciate your concern and corporation. These are interesting, but I'd like to know the opinion from the Veda.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I take Vedic opinions as authoritative. Unless Kanad explained paramanu quoting Veda, my question won't be solved.